# ACLs vs group permissions in linux

Tags: linux, file-permissions, acl

I would like to allow a set of students to access a shared web-server. Students work in groups, and each group's home directory contains a `www` folder that should be accessible to the shared instance of apache2. For example, if Bob and John are part of group MyPetShop, you would have user `john` in the `john students mypetshop` groups. I do not want to grant `www-data` membership to students, to avoid them messing up other people's pages directly*.

And their home directy would be at `/home/students/mypetshop`, with `/home/students/mypetshop/www` being read/write for user `www-data`. I can achieve this either using

- a sticky group of `www-data` for these folders (so that their permissions would be `drwxrwsrwx john www-data`). This has the problem of john using the wrong permissions for his files, so that bob or www-data cannot access them; or www-data creating files that john and bob can only touch once they fiddle around with permissions for a while.
- standard group ownership (`mypetshop`), and an ACL that would allow `www-data` access to these folders (via `setfacl -m d:g:www-data:rwx www`).

Would ACLs work here as intended? Are default ACLs automatically inherited in subfolders, or is there some much easier way to set this up that I am missing?.

---

(*) *yes, this is not fool-proof, as they could write www-data-executed phps to do that for them...*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implemented the ACL version, and it works like a charm. Students cannot mess up their group permissions using standard SSH/SFTP clients (which are not ACL-aware). Definitely recommended for a shared-hosting, not-very-high-security setup.

The sequence is:

1. Add the ACL tools `setfacl` and `getfacl` (debian/ubuntu package `acl`)
2. Add the `acl` option to the relevant filesystem in your `/etc/fstab` (filesystems without this mount-option silently ignore any ACLs; this is confusing at best).
3. Use `setfacl` to allow user `www-data` directory traversal access to all `/home/stucents/*/www` folders
4. Use `setfacl` to allow, within each `www` folder, default (= sticky) read-write-execute access for members of the relevant group, and user `www-data`

Any file or folder created in a folder with a default ACL will inherit the ACL.